# Same degree input's val

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>surname</td>
    <td id="dummy"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>name2</td>
    <td>surname</td>
    <td id="dummy"></td>
    </tr>
    ....
```

i want to select with jquery when `$(td[id='dummy]).val()==somecondition` {select first td's val in same degree with `<td id="dummy">`

How can i select with jQuery?

Comment: ID's should be unique !

Comment: What do you mean by same degree? And calling `val()` on a td won't return anything, I believe you want to call `text()`.

Comment: you need to replace id with class and in place of val use innerHTML. This will help you to get anything inside each td having same class name.

Answer (score -1):

i have solved to use this code,

```
 var id = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:first").text().trim();
```

Comment: This makes no sense in relation to your question.